# How can I have ExpressJS reload script under development?

Tags: node.js, express

How, if possible, can I get an ExpressJS server app (i.e. a nodejs script) to restart on modification?  I'm thinking about Flask, in **python**, which allows me to set an environment variable or call `app.run(debug=True)` so that on changes to a server script (while it's running!), the server is automatically stopped and script restarted.

How would I modify the following, simple ExpressJS server app, to get the same behavior during development?

```
const app = require('express')();
const port = 3001;

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!\n'));
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Starting @ ${port}!`))
```

Comment: Use nodemon: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon